# Text to Binary with Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a short VBA function that produces a binary representation of a text string:

```
Public Function TextToBin(S As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, L As Long

    L = Len(S)
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For i = 1 To L
            TextToBin = TextToBin & .Dec2Bin(Asc(Mid(S, i, 1)))
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

I have been asked to replace this UDF with a simple formula so the application can run in a macro-free environment.

My current workaround is to place:

```
=IFERROR(DEC2BIN(CODE(MID($A$1,COLUMNS($A:A),1))),"")
```

in cell **B1** and copy across.  Then, in another cell, use:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,B1:IV1)
```

However, I do not want to admit that the best we can do is to use over sixteen thousand helper cells!

Is there a simple, compact method to get the same result ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this as an array:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,DEC2BIN(CODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1))),1))))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: SUPER COOL ! .....I did not realize that *TEXTJOIN()* supports internal arrays...if I could upvote this twice, I would!

Comment: Wow, I *really* need to get a grip on those *array formulas*!

Comment: It really is one of the coolest thing that Excel has added in a long time. @Gary'sStudent.

Comment: Excel 2019 or Office365 is needed for `textjoin`

Comment: @mattwilkie `TEXTJOIN` is only available in Office 365 and Office 2019.  There are many vba UDFs out there that mimic the use. Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: This is great. Would you be able to take that and turn it back to "Jim"?